# How do dynamically hide cells/sheets without macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I recently created a company excel workbook that used to have an a lot of rarely used columns/cells and was tasked with making it simpler but still universal.

I was able to create a checkbox with VBA code and when the box is checked it will show Sheet X. Unchecking it hides Sheet X. I made a similar checkbox inside a sheet to hide extra columns. Below is the VBA routine for hiding worksheets.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email Settings").Visible = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

However the hangup now is that I can't email it to customers because our company Exchange server blocks Excel files with macros. I have sent it with Dropbox shared link however does not allow the customers to upload without an account and some customers may straight up block Dropbox.

Is there a non-VBA solution alternative to use an Active X checkbox to dynamically pick columns or sheets to hide?

Comment: No, not without VBA and macros enabled

Comment: A way of hiding columns without using VBA would be to use the "Group" functionality in the Data ribbon. Grouped columns can be hidden and unhidden by clicking on a "+"  or "-" symbol above the top row. I can't think of an equivalent for hiding worksheets.

Comment: You could try `Custom Views` in the `Workbook Views` group under `View`. It works for columns and worksheets, but I've found it to be erratic sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Using Custom Views:

This example hides a column (`B`), a row (`2`), and a sheet (`HIDE THIS SHEET`).

[image: Unhidden]

[image: Hidden]

Once you have hidden what you want to hide, then add a custom view.

[image: Starting Custom View]

[image: Adding Custom View]

Unhide all of your data (you might want to add another custom view to make all of your data unhidden) then select your custom view and click show.

[image: Selecting Custom View]

And you will see this:

[image: Hidden]

Comment: I haven't yet tried this, but if it works, it is a much undervalued non-macro solution!

Comment: @cartbeforehorse, the caveat is that many changes you make to your spreadsheet can possible confuse the view and then you have to redo it.  I've never documented the types of changes, I just redo it if it starts to look different.